# Find the cursor position on a GtkSourceView window

Tags: python, pygtk

I want to display a popup window with an auto-complete combo, how do I identify the current cursor screen position to setup the auto-complete popup window ?

Comment: Why? Doesn't [`GtkSourceCompletion`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtksourceview/stable/GtkSourceCompletion.html) automatically do that for you?

Comment: GtkSourceCompletion is not flexible enough for me, I need more control of the completion presentation window.

Comment: I was going to tell you to look at the source code of `GtkSourceCompletion`, but you've already done that. +1 to your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution looking into the gtk source completion code:

```
def get_iter_pos(text_view, iter):
      iter_location = text_view.get_iter_location(iter)
      win_location = text_view.buffer_to_window_coords(
            Gtk.TextWindowType.WIDGET, iter_location.x, iter_location.y)                

        win = text_view.get_window (Gtk.TextWindowType.WIDGET);
        view_pos = win.get_position()

        xx = win_location[0] + view_pos[0]
        yy = win_location[1]+ view_pos[1] + iter_location.height;           
        return (xx, yy, iter_location.height)
buffer = view.get_buffer()
insert_iter = buffer.get_iter_at_mark(buffer.get_insert())
x, y, height = get_iter_pos(widget, insert_iter)
top_x, top_y = widget.get_toplevel().get_position()
mywindow.move(top_x+x, top_y+y)
```